# Is it possible to put multiple Operating Systems on a single CD/DVD (NOT USB) and be able to run them individually?

Tags: boot, cd

How do I install like fedora and Ubuntu on the same cd so I don't have to have like 20 cd's for os's?

Comment: See http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/94398-super-disc-multi-boot-project-cddvd-using-isolinux/ which, unfortunately, requires Windows to create it. It also requires a DVD, as a CD does not have the capacity for both Ubuntu and Fedora. Since it requires Windows, I don't think it qualifies as a bona fide answer...

Comment: Windows is no barrier cause I've got a bootcamped windows mac. Thanks for the quick reply, I thought I might have to wait a while for a response.

Comment: Can you guys make an answer so i can select one as the answer?

Comment: Hello? Can you guys please do that?

Comment: @user68186 check my comment please

Comment: @K7AAY check my comment please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try MultiCD**

From its site:

[Multicd](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/index.html) is a shell script designed to build a multiboot CD image containing many different Linux distributions and/or utilities.

Even though the name has CD in it, it works for DVDs as well.

**Steps**

1. Make sure your ISO files are among the supported distributions listed [HERE](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/#SupportedDistros).
2. [Download the script from the MultiCD page](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/#Downloads). Note that starting with version 5.x, you can download MultiCD in two formats: single script called "*combined*" and a script with a plugins folder called "*separate*").
3. Put the downloaded files in a folder along with the supported ISO images (or symbolic links) and then make the script executable. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter: `chmod +x multicd*.sh`.
4. Run the script: `sudo ./multicd*.sh`

**Reference**

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/multicd-builds-multi-boot-cd-dvd-with.html

I hope this helps.